# jQuery function is returning more events for a Modal click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a website where there are three different modal buttons and I wrote a variable to get the values in a data layer which is working good but when I first click on the button I get 2 events and it starts doubling up for each click afterwards.

Here is my code

```
function() {
  
    if ({{Click Text}} == 'STUDY DESIGN'){
  
      $(this).each(function() {
      $(this).on("click", function(){
           var imageText = $({{Click Element}}).closest('.d-md-flex').find('.image-wrapper img.image__desktop').attr("alt");
         window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
         window.dataLayer.push({
         'event': 'studyDesignInteraction',
         'action': imageText
        });
      });
  });
       return true;
     }
  }
```

[image: GTM Assistant]

The first click comes back with two events and it keeps doubling up after each event. How can I only apply to one click?

Comment: `this` is window in your code

Comment: hi mplungjan! thanks for the answer but could not understand what exactly you mean?

Comment: What do YOU think `$(this)`  is?

Comment: Is a random `function () { }` specific to google-analytics/tag-manager?   If it's just js/jquery then it will need to be called from somewhere, looks like that "somewhere" is calling it every "outer" click.

Comment: whatever it is that I have clicked on the website, which gets me the values I need but I am getting them too many times.

Answer (score 1):

$(this) in your code is `window`

```js
$(this).each(function() { console.log(Object.keys(this)[0])
  $(this).on("click", function() { console.log(Object.keys(this)[0])
    var imageText = $('img').closest('.d-md-flex').find('.image-wrapper img.image__desktop').attr("alt");
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'studyDesignInteraction',
      'action': imageText
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="x" class="d-md-flex">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img class="image__desktop" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but I am still getting more events that I should. It is starting at 1 this time and increase by 2 in each click.

Comment: Then you call your function in a click or other event